# Append Number to Section of Similar Line

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a sorted text file made up of key/value pairs in the format

```
"String" = int,
```

These were sorted using the UNIX sort utility. For example:

```
"'Nessy's Trophy Pincers" = 81859,
"1 Handed Alliance Sword" = 119204,
"1 Handed Horde Axe" = 119206,
"10 Pound Mud Snapper" = 6292,
"100 Year Soy Sauce" = 74853,
"103 Pound Mightfish" = 13917,
"113 Pound Swordfish" = 39147,
"12 Pound Lobster" = 13909,
"12 Pound Mud Snapper" = 6294,
...
```

However, some of these strings are duplicates while having different numbers:

```
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder" = 99047,
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder" = 99197,
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder" = 99411,
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder" = 99603,
"Battlescar Boots" = 28747,
...
```

I would like to append a number to the duplicates so that the above segment would look like this:

```
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder" = 99047,
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder 1" = 99197,
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder 2" = 99411,
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder 3" = 99603,
"Battlescar Boots" = 28747,
...
```

What would I have to type, using sed or awk or any other command line utility, to do this for me?

Comment: Are the numbers after the `=` unique across the whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'" *= *' 'c[$1]++{sub(FS," "c[$1]"&")}1' file
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder" = 99047,
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder 2" = 99197,
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder 3" = 99411,
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder 4" = 99603,
"Battlescar Boots" = 28747,
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it in bash. Reads form stdin, writes to stdout

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A known  # an associative array

while read line
do

   eval set $line

   string="$1"
   number="$3"

   i="${known["$string"]}"

   if test -z "$i"
   then
      known["$string"]=0
   else
      let ++i
      known["$string"]=$i
      string="$string $i"
   fi

   echo '"'"$string"'"' = $number

done
```

The version above does not require the source to be sorted. If you have very large input, you might prefer the following version which makes use of the fact that the input is sorted and does not need an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash

saved=

while read line
do

   eval set $line

   string="$1"
   number="$3"

   if [ "$string" != "$saved" ]
   then
      i=0
   else
      let ++i
      string="$string $i"
   fi

   saved="$1"

   echo '"'"$string"'"' = $number

done
```

Comment: Will fail in many interesting ways given various contents of the input file. Any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using perl from command line,

```
perl -pe 's/"(.+)\K(?=")/( map $_ ? " $_" : "", $h{$1}++ )[0]/e' file
```

Comment: Nice one.. I think it needs to extract the first element from the list returned from `map` to work properly.. As it is now, the `map` function returns a `1` for all lines.. This worked for me: `perl -pe 's/"(.+)\K(?=")/(map {$_ ? " $_" : ""} $h{$1}++)[0] /e' file` ..

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes, tnx for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Balanced qw(extract_delimited);

my $fn = 'File';
my %h;
open (my $fh, "<", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!\n";
while (<$fh>) {
    my ($title, $remainder) = extract_delimited($_, '"', '[^"]*');
    if ($h{$title}++) {
        $title = modify_title($title, $h{$title});
    }
    print "${title}$remainder";
}
close($fh);

sub modify_title {
    my ($title, $n) = @_;

    $n--;
    $title =~ s/"$/ $n"/;
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
awk -F\" '{a[$2]++} {if (a[$2]-1) $0=FS$2" "a[$2]FS$3}1' file
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder" = 99047,
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder 2" = 99197,
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder 3" = 99411,
"Battleplate of the Prehistoric Marauder 4" = 99603,
"Battlescar Boots" = 28747,
```

The duplicate does not need to be in sequence.

Another version:

```
awk -F= '{a[$1]++} {if (a[$1]-1) sub(/[^^]\"/," "a[$1]"\"")}1' file
```